# How can I calculate this hard complex integral?

Tags: complex-analysis, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

**Overview**

I want to calculate this integral via complex analysis:

$$I(x) = \cfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\cfrac{\log\zeta(s)}{s}x^s\mathrm{d}s,$$
where i is the imaginary unit, c > 1 and log is the natural logarithm. I already have a rough idea how I may solve this integral but it also could be wrong. I know the solution, it's
$$I(x) = \operatorname{Li}(x)-\sum_\rho\operatorname{Li}(x^\rho)-\log2+\int_{x}^{\infty}\cfrac{\mathrm{d}t}{t(t^2-1)\log t},$$
where \rho are the nontrivial zeros of the Riemann-Zeta function.
But how can I derive to that solution step by step?

**My Rough idea**

We know that
$$\log\zeta(s) = \sum_{\rho}\log\left(1-\cfrac{s}{\rho}\right)-\log2-\log\Gamma\left(1+\cfrac{s}{2}\right)+\cfrac{s}{2}\log\pi-\log(s-1).$$
Is it possible to evaluate these terms seperately? If yes, please show how, if no, please explain another method step by step.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you seen the analogous calculation where $\log\zeta(s)$ is replaced by $-\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)$, which is the standard proof of the prime number theorem? Many sources give the details of pulling the contour to the left, picking up the residues at the poies, and showing that the error terms tend to $0$; all of those can be used as models for the steps of the calculation you want to do. One difference is that your integrand has branch-cut singularities, so you will need to use Hankel contours or something similar. It's not realistic to ask a volunteer on the internet to show you every step.

Comment: while I second the comment of @Greg, I can suggest taking a look at Edwards book on RZ as the computation is done there in detail from page 25 to page 33

Comment: ... and I would add that a question which is (supposed to be) considered in a book might be answered with a quote/excerpt from the book, which is likely not what you're looking for; I'm sure it's far more productive to ask what exactly you don't understand there.